# Permissions for sched_setscheduler

Tags: android, linux, scheduling

What privileges does a process need to change it's scheduling policy? I've tried to set SCHED_FIFO policy (running platform service on Android) and failed with EPERM.

```
    struct sched_param param;
    memset(&param, 0, sizeof(param));
    int max_prio_for_policy = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
    param.sched_priority = max_prio_for_policy; 

    if(0 != sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &param)) ...
```

And generally, what permissions are needed for a process to elevate it's priority? Is it allowed for root only? Can user process increase it's priority?